# Is it possible to use `keyof` operator on literals instead of interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I have an object literal such as the following (all properties are known at compile time):

```
const foo = {
  "hello": "hola"
};
```

If `foo` were an interface rather than a variable, I could easily do something like

```
/** THEORETICAL ONLY - Does not compile! */
function translate(input: keyof foo): string {
  return foo[input];
}
```

However, doing so with a variable does not work, since the compiler cannot find an interface with the name `foo`.

Does Typescript support `keyof` operations on object literals whose values are known at compile time?

Answer (score 245, accepted):

`keyof` operates on types, but `foo` is a value. But the `typeof` operator takes a value and produces its type, so you can use `keyof typeof foo` to do this.

Note that this only works if you haven't associated an interface with the object literal (thanks *radicand*).

Comment: This compiles but doesn't actually provide any feeback on the string I pass. I can put whatever I want in there and it won't complain.

Comment: Note that this only works if you haven't associated an interface with the object literal.

Comment: @radicand 's comment seems very important in this answer. Might be worth an edit.

Comment: Please edit the answer and  update it with @radicand comment cause it won't work otherwise. anyway one of the best answers i have seen on SO.

Comment: Is there any way to get the keys of an object to which you want to associate an interface? I want my object to comply with `Vuex.MutationTree<State>` while at the same time storing in a type the union of mutations (i.e. the keys of the object).

Comment: @DanielM did you ever figure that out? I'm also trying to add some type safety to that interface.

Comment: @CraigHarshbarger I have experimented with creating a safer version of the Vuex store, although it is still a work in progress and it has a few limitations. Nevertheless, maybe you find answers to your question on it – bit.ly/2C9uc8O (In short, I'm going down one level, defining `MutationTree` myself as a generic type, then applying `keyof` to it.)

Comment: @DanielM that looks like exactly what I've been attempting to do. Could you provide an example of how to use it? I'm attempting to do so but must be missing something

Comment: Maybe we can continue this side conversation over in Gist :) https://gist.github.com/inad9300/d3da1744974d1ce4b0c3c84f4e287e42

Answer (score 11):

a bit off, while i'm finding indexer key to literals, but put it here for future reference.

```
const foo = {
  "hello": "hola"
};

let data: { [key in keyof typeof foo]:number} & { name: string, index: number }[] = [] as any;

data.foo = 1;
data[0] = {name:'foo', 1};
```

Answer (score 0):

For those on newer typescript version, this should work:

```
const foo = {
  "foo": "FOO",
  "bar": "BAR"
} as const

type fooKey = keyof typeof foo
```

and now `fooKey` will have the type `"foo" | "bar"`.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoGMBECQ4BcuAYgPJk4A0WuARgIYBORuAQgIIBKOGAvjAYQYoSFAwYoATwAOAU3iIA0nKkoYAa1Ug4MafJ2KQGIA)